# Load data into Redshift using Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-redshift

What are some ways of inserting data into Amazon Redshift using node.js?

This should be pretty straightforward, but I was unable to find any concrete example for efficient loading.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way of doing that would be to load the data into S3 using [AWS node.js SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) (there's an [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html) in the documentation), then use [node-pg](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) to [COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html) the data into Redshift :

```
var pg = require('pg');

var conString = "postgres://user:password@db-endpoint:port/schema";

var client = new pg.Client(conString);
    client.connect(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
      }

      //assuming credentials are exported as enviornment variables, 
      //both CLI- and S3cmd-style are supported here.
      //Also, you may want to specify the file's format (e.g. CSV), 
      //max errors, etc.
      var copyCmd = 'copy my_redshift_table from \'s3://your_bucket/your_file\' credentials \'aws_access_key_id=' 
      + (process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY || process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
      + ';aws_secret_access_key=' 
      + (process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY || process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
      + '\'';

      client.query(copyCmd, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
          return console.error('error running query', err);
        }
        logger.info("redhshift load: no errors, seem to be successful!");
        client.end();
      });
    });
```

Note that you don't need any special drivers for this to run.

Comment: Accepted own answer because question is resolved and enough time had passed. However I'll happily change to any better answer if one appears.

Comment: Do you have any experience using pg's `pool` module to issue COPY commands?

Comment: @js87 - no, I didn't try using the pool module. If you do and it turns out to be better than plain pg please post an additional answer!